# Different security measures for websites (HTTP Headers, etc.)

Tags: javascript, security, http-headers, html

This is a bit of an open-ended question and I apologize for this. But I think it is useful and I hope it won't be closed.

I'm working on a website that is handling highly sensitive content and I am looking to make it as secure as I possibly can.

Just now I ran across the `X-Frame-Options` HTTP-Header with which I can [disallow the page to be shown inside a frame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options) and thus prevent ["clickjacking"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking) attacks on my page.

Is there some reference that you might suggest which provides a comprehensive list of all security measures that I should know about (e.g. SSL (of course), HTTP-Headers like `Strict-Transport-Security` and `X-Content-Security-Policy`, Client-Side AES-Encryption, ...)?

Are there other (maybe less known) security features that you would consider relevant for me to look into (e.g. is it possible to block plugins, prevent bookmarklets, disallow proxied browsers like Opera Mini, ...)?

I am hoping that the answers to this question will together lead to a useful checklist to make sure I (and others) am not missing any major security features for protecting content.

Comment: This is really too open-ended. At the very least you need to be very specific about the threats you need to protect against. But this question really needs to be closed -- this is not an open-ended discussion site, it has to be possible for someone to post a single answer that gets accepted as the solution.

Comment: From the FAQ: _If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much._ I think your question fits that description of an inappropriate question.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks Barmar... Just what I was hoping for... The whole point of this is to learn about threats that I HAVEN'T considered. How would you propose to rephrase it.

Comment: @Barmar I'm not looking for a book. I'm looking for a bullet-list with maybe 20 points on it.

Comment: It doesn't matter how you phrase it, it's not an appropriate question. Another way to view it: if you can't tell when the question has been answered, it's not a good question.

Comment: @Barmar: Can you make a suggestion how I can make this question fit SO format better?

Comment: SO simply isn't the right place to look for what you want. Aren't there security-related forums?

Comment: Yes. it's http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: IT Security stackexchange does include web app hardening, but topic still OK here.  I agree the question should be edited to be a bit more focused, maybe on HTTP headers.

Comment: Such headers are useful but should not be relied upon; according to [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security), IE doesn't support HSTS at all.

Answer (score 2):

Start with the [Open Web Application Security Project Top 10 vulnerabilities document](http://owasptop10.googlecode.com/files/OWASP%20Top%2010%20-%202013%20-%20RC1.pdf). If you can take the proper measures to avoid the vulnerabilities described there, you will be more secure than the vast majority of sites out there. After that, it might be time to get help from security specialists, do some penetration testing, look to resolve more obscure vulnerabilities, etc.

Comment: +1 Awesome! This is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for! Looks like I got these points covered... :)

Answer (score 2):

For the HTTP Headers aspect of the question, take a look at the [Secure HTTP Headers](http://www.slideshare.net/akashm/secure-http-headers-c0c0n-2011-akash-mahajan) slideshare presentation and the Mozilla Developer Network [Securing your site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/Securing_your_site) document.

Here are some specific HTTP Response Headers

- Set-Cookie ([Secure and HttpOnly attributes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Secure_and_HttpOnly))
- [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options)
- [X-XSS-Protection](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/01/31/controlling-the-internet-explorer-xss-filter-with-the-x-xss-protection-http-header.aspx)
- [X-Content-Type-Options](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/07/02/ie8-security-part-v-comprehensive-protection.aspx)
- [X-Content-Security-Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/CSP/Introducing_Content_Security_Policy) or [Content-Security-Policy](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/)
- [Strict-Transport-Security](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security)

Note, that different browsers and their versions have differing levels of support, so aside from secure and httponly cookies, your IE7 users may not see any benefit.